# Creating Certificate Signing Request on Windows

Tags: windows, go

Is there a way to create a CSR using Go on Windows. I need the private key to be stored in the windows certificate store.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can with openssl, i dont know Go. http://blog.didierstevens.com/2015/03/30/howto-make-your-own-cert-with-openssl-on-windows/

Comment: CertificateRequest represents a PKCS #10, certificate signature request [https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#CreateCertificateRequest](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#CreateCertificateRequest)